# How can I execute javascript rendering in sitecore

Tags: .net, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore9

I want to know how we can execute javascript rendering in Sitecore. I can see some documents (https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/mvc-integration/javascript-rendering) in sitecore but it is not clear on how to execute javascript rendering.

Please could anyone help?

Comment: It sounds like you need to have a conversation with somebody as this is a very generic question without much shown as to what you have tried.

Perhaps you should try joining the Sitecore Slack (sitecore.chat) and ask a few questions in the #jss channel until you can get to a more specific question with some code examples of what you are trying and what is not working.

Comment: hey @JayS I have registered sitecore.chat how long it will typically take for them to  send me invite link?

Comment: I am not certain how long it takes, the community admins do what they can as it is community-run, but it is usually not very long.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using html also.

1.You need to create a html file which includes script src link

2.In sitecore you need to create a view rendering.

3.Add that view rendering to your content page with placeholder name.

4.Add that placeholder in the view where you want those script files.

you can also user rendering parameters with switch case and use same html file for different contents

Comment: I want to execute javascript on the server side. In that case how should I invoke it?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are saying about server side. Are you saying about bundles in server side. even with bundles also the process is same.

Comment: Can I extend layout service with jss alone? ( Without .net)

Comment: I was talking about server.bundle.js. it is getting invoked in nodejs viewEngine. Is it possible to call external apis with javascript on server side and merge its response to LayoutService response using jss only?